# Javascript proxy on Array.push() don't trigger set?

Tags: javascript, proxy

I'm working with proxies and everything was working alright, until I added an array property on the object my proxy was attached to :

```js
let input = document.querySelector('input')
input.addEventListener('change', e => {
  let val = e.target.value
  proxObj.foo = val
  proxObj.fooArray.push(val)
})

let obj = {
  foo: "bar", //log : foo mutated to whatever
  fooArray: [] //never logs
}

proxObj = new Proxy(obj, {
  set: (target, prop, val) => {
    console.log(prop, "mutated to", val)
    target[prop] = val
    return true
  }
})
```

```html
<input type='text'>

<button onClick="console.log(obj.fooArray)"> log fooArray</button>
```

As you can see here, I expect fooArray to be printed on mutation, but it's not happening. What am i doing wrong here?

Comment: You're pushing to the `fooArray`, not to the proxy. When you mutate the `proxObj` it works as expected.

Comment: so I should set a proxy on the fooArray too?

Comment: Yes, to watch the properties of the array you will need to wrap in a proxy as well.